# Template form text box validation in Play Framework 2.3

Tags: playframework

In the views html, I can put "required" to a text box to make it a required field. what should i put for a text box if it is required to be a URL?

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="txtName" value="" required>

<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="txtUrl" value="" ???>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, from what you have done, I don't think you used play framework template. Instead, it looks like you use HTML5, in case it's true then you can use something like this:

```
Add your homepage: <input type="url" name="homepage">
```

For more info: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp

Comment: I indeed used the view template in play framework. in order to make the example simpler, i removed the @variables. The HTML5 validations will also do the trick. Thanks!